# convergence in distribution of normal distributions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, normal-distribution

Let $\mu_n$ have a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $n$. Then, $\mu_n((-\infty, x]) \to 1/2$ for all $x$?

The statement is from Rick Rurrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*. I am a little confused. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Let $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be a standard normal variable. Then $\mu_n$ can be realized as the law of $\sqrt{n}Z$, and so, $$\mu_{n}((-\infty, x])=\mathbb{P}[\sqrt{n}Z\leq x]=\mathbb{P}[Z\leq x/\sqrt{n}]\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\mathbb{P}[Z\leq 0]=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I was a bit confused, but now it is clear!